# adding NSLayoutConstraint between two objects

Tags: ios, iphone, nslayoutconstraint

I am having a problem adding a constraint between a web view and a tool bar. I am using the following code but getting an error.

```
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary6 = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(newWebView, self.bottomToolBar);
NSArray *constraint6 =[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[newWebView]-(0)-[bottomToolBar]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary6];

for (int i = 0; i<constraint6.count; i++)
{
    [self.view addConstraint:constraint6[i]];
}
```

I am trying to copy a similar constraint that is automatically generated from IB.

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8b876b0 V:[UIWebView:0x8c53560]-(0)-[UIToolbar:0x9844400]>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties passed into `NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings()` have a different name (I can't remember what it is).

If you pass a property in rather than an iVar for example `self.bottomToolBar` the key will be **self.bottomToolBar** however using a "**.**" in the visual format will cause syntax errors when it is parsed.

Try passing the synthesized iVar in instead:

```
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary6 = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(newWebView, _bottomToolBar);
NSArray *constraint6 =[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[newWebView]-(0)-[_bottomToolBar]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary6];
[self.view addConstraints:constraint6];
```